# Chrome Drop Folder - incomplete files

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dropzone.js

i'm working on an uploader with drop folder support, it was ok, but i'm failing a use case.

I have a folder with multiple files and folders inside, the amount of files are 2511, and 2451 folders. I dont know the reason, but after the drop function it only recognize 1576 files with their parents folders.

Simplified this is the drop function i'm using:

```
        filescnt=0;
        nop=0;
        $("#dropingArea").on('dragover',function(e){            
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $("#dropingArea").on('dragenter',function(e){            
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $("#dropingArea").on('drop',function(e){
            console.log(e);
            if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
                if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    /*UPLOAD FILES HERE*/
                    console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items);
                    items = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items;
                    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                        var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
                        if (item) {
                            traverseFileTree(item);
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        });

        function traverseFileTree(item, path) {
              path = path || "";
              if (item.isFile) {
                // Get file
                filescnt++;
                item.file(function(file) {
                  console.log("File:", path + file.name);
                });
              } else if (item.isDirectory) {
                // Get folder contents
                var dirReader = item.createReader();
                dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                  for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    traverseFileTree(entries[i], path + item.name + "/");
                  }
                });
              }
        }
```

Now the problem seems to be also on dropzone and plupload.

i've tested the same folder on 
http://protonet.github.io/plupload/examples/drag_and_drop.html
same ammount as result.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/
same ammount as result.

I appreciate any help
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

> To read the contents of a directory, create a DirectoryReader and call
>   its readEntries() method. There is no guarantee that all of a
>   directory's entries will be returned in a single call to
>   readEntries(). That means you need to keep calling
>   DirectoryReader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.

And again from the above page:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

  var dirReader = fs.root.createReader();
  var entries = [];

  // Call the reader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.
  var readEntries = function() {
     dirReader.readEntries (function(results) {
      if (!results.length) {
        listResults(entries.sort());
      } else {
        entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
        readEntries();
      }
    }, errorHandler);
  };

  readEntries(); // Start reading dirs.

}
```

Notice that in the case where we've read *some* results (results.length != 0), we invoke readEntries against the same dirReader to get the next "chunk" of files.